# How to keep only those directories and file under same directory which are new when compare two directories in UNIX

Tags: unix, diff

I have two date folder directories, under that there are different devices directories and under those there are log files. I want to compare two date directories and keep only new device directory or new log file under old device directory.

As of now I have done

```
diff -r dir1 dir2 | grep dir1 | awk '{print $4}' > difference1.txt
```

But i want that the new directories and files should be present in dir1 only and rest get deleted

Comment: Also put what you've done so far to solve the problem.

Comment: diff -r dir1 dir2 | grep dir1 | awk '{print $4}' > difference1.txt

But i want that the new directories and files should be present in dir1 only and rest get deleted

Comment: Ah ! much better now.

Comment: Wondering if you ever figured this out?